# E001 error? How can I remove the swiftshader icon?

Tags: fifa-13

I installed Fifa 13 and I got the `E001` error. Luckily, I managed to solve the problem using the Swiftshader 3D rendering program. Now while playing FIFA 13 there is a large icon of Swiftshader on the bottom left corner, and it disturbs me while playing.  Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

In the options for Fifa 13, disable VSync. This may solve the initial error.

I've no idea what Swiftshader is, but I assume if you uninstall/disable it the watermark will go away. Otherwise, generally such watermarks are meant as an incentive to purchase the full version of a software -- so try that?

Comment: if I uninstall swiftshader fifa wont start it will show `E001` error

Comment: There should be a `fifaconfig.exe` or similar that you can use to configure the settings.

Comment: I did I tried decreasing the resolution and all other stuffs possible but I guess i am not lucky